# Creating a record using SforceEnterpriseClient with reference

Tags: soap, php

Using SforceEnterpriseClient, I'm having difficulty creating a new record of a custom type that has a reference to a record of another type (incidentally it is custom as well).
System_User__c is a custom type that corresponds to system users associated with a given SalesForce Account.
Task_Completions__c is a custom type that tracks the number of times that system user has completed a task of a given type.

Here are the relevant sections of the WSDL:

```
<complexType name="System_User__c">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="ens:sObject">
      <sequence>
        <element name="Account__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
        <element name="Account__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Account"/>
        ...
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>  
</complexType>

<complexType name="Task_Completions__c">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="ens:sObject">
      <sequence>
        <element name="SystemUser__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
        <element name="SystemUser__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:System_User__c"/>
        <element name="Task" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="Completions" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
        ...
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>  
</complexType>
```

The following snippet demonstrates the ways that I've tried to set this up and the errors I'm getting as a result of each:

```
$taskCompletion = new stdClass();
$taskCompletion->Task = 'submit invoice';
$taskCompletion->Completions = 5;

// First attempt - straight ID association
$taskCompletion->SystemUser__c = <SOME SALESFORCE ID>;

// Second attempt - taking a hint from the partner version of the SOAP client, I'm wrapping the System User reference in its own object, ID only
$systemUserRef = new stdClass();
$systemUserRef->Id = <SOME SALESFORCE ID>;
$record->SystemUser__c = $systemUserRef;

$response = $sforceConnection->create(array($taskCompletion), 'Task_Completions__c');
// First attempt fails with: [message] => System User: id value of incorrect type: 003D0000020823MIAQ, [statusCode] => FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
// Second attempt fails with: Create Task_Completions__c Failure with message "Unexpected element {}Id during simple type deserialization"
```

I've also tried changing _convertToAny() as mentioned in this post https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008sthIAA because it appears that the SOAP client is choking on the nested object structure.
I know this should be something easy and apologize in advance if a simple example exists in documentation or on some forum post somewhere but I've searched high and low and haven't had any luck.

Thanks